# How to draw smooth boundary for the image through the edge points in matlab

Tags: matlab, boundary

I have a segmented region as shown in figure 1. and i want to plot the lower boundary using matlab by connecting the lower edge points as shown in figure 2. I cannot plot like fig 2. So I did some morphological operations like fill,thicken,close but not getting the idea to plot.can you provide the matlab code.

figure 1

[image]

figure 2

[image]

Comment: Start by defining in prose what "lower edge points are". From your picture it seems that the are not "lowest y coordinate" and not "convex envelope". Though not being a convex envelope might just be imprecision of your red line. (interesting picture by the way, triggers phantasy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution

- Threshold the image so it is just in binary, easy since this image is simple
- Identify the position of the lowest pixel in each column
- Smooth by just taking the max of every nth column. *If you just want the lowest points then you can stop at line 4 of the below code!*

Code is commented for more detail:

```
img = rgb2gray(imread('1.jpg')); % Read image
img = img > 0.5;                 % Threshold to get binary image
% Get last row where there is a 1 pixel in the image for each column
lastrow = max(repmat((1:size(img,1))', 1, size(img,2)).*img,[],1);
res = 30;                        % Pixel resolution for line averaging
% Ensure res divides num. columns by padding the end of the vector
lastrowpadded = [lastrow, NaN(1, res - mod(numel(lastrow),res))]; 
% Reshape into columns of length 'res', then get the max row number
lastrow2 = max(reshape(lastrowpadded,res,[]),[],1);
% Plots
imshow(img); 
hold on
plot(1:size(img,2), lastrow, '.')
plot(res/2:res:size(lastrowpadded,2)-res/2, lastrow2, 'linewidth', 1.5)
hold off
legend('lowest points', 'smoothed lowest points')
```

Result:

[image: grouped max]

**Note:** because the image is plotted with (0,0) in the upper-left corner, this plot will be upside down if you plotted it without the image. Subtract the `lastrow2` or `lastrow` values from the height of the image to rectify this.

---

Edit: You might also be interested in [`convhull`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) for creating a convex hull

```
[X,Y] = find(img); % After thresholding image as before, get X,Y coords
K = convhull(X,Y); % Get convex hull indices
imshow(img)        % Show image
hold on    
plot(Y(K),X(K),'linewidth',1.5) % Plot convex hull
```

Result:

[image: convhull]

Comment: Can we find the highest points and draw using the above concept??

Comment: Yes, where I got `lastrow`using `max`, get the first row using `min`